# After removing the item form the list again it is coming

Tags: android

My issue is item is deleted from the list view and after deleting when I press back button and again going to list same deleted item is coming. I have also added my code in below. Please help me on this issue and save my time.

```
 // in Activity


 lstMembers.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(GroupInfoActivity.this)

                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setMessage("Are You Sure You Want to Delete This Note?!")
                        .setTitle("Attempt to Delete A Note")
                        .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                try {
                                    if(groupMemberAdapter!=null){
                                        groupMemberAdapter.removeObject(position);
                                        groupMemberAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                        Toast.makeText(GroupInfoActivity.this, "ooooooh No!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                Toast.makeText(GroupInfoActivity.this, "Good Choice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                return true;
            }
        });

//in Adapter

 public void removeObject (int position) {

        this.groupMemberList.remove(position);
    }
```

Comment: you are removing the item from your listview only not from the data you are getting. So whenever you get your data again the item shows up.

Comment: From where does the `ListView` get all data ? Remove that note from the source too.

Comment: ok i will do it. if any problem then I will ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void removeObject (int position) {
    this.groupMemberList.remove(position);
}
```

This looks like you're deleting it only in-memory, but you have to remove it from the database/ from wherever it comes to make it not show up again.